# How to return total amount of colors without interfering with JSON_ARRAYAGG and LIMIT in FROM subquery

Tags: mysql, json, subquery, common-table-expression, json-arrayagg

The product has two colors (Black and White)

I would like to use a LIMIT to not bring all the colors... and the amount of colors would be the total

---

Example:

LIMIT 1 would return:

- colorsName: *"[{"color": "Black"}]"*
- amountColors: *int(2)*

LIMIT 2 would return:

- colorsName: *[{"color": "Black"}, {"color": "White"}]*
- amountColors: *int(2)*

---

I have to return the names, inside a JSON

But I saw that there is no way to use LIMIT in JSON_ARRAYAGG

The solution would be to use a **subquery in FROM**

It worked... and I had to add the GROUP BY v.id

- LIMIT 1 returns only one color (OK)
- LIMIT 2 returns both colors (OK)

**BUT** the amount of colors ( amountColors ) is always 1
It should be 2 in the above two cases

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        pdv.variation_id
    FROM product_detail pd
        INNER JOIN product_detail_variation pdv
            ON (pdv.product_detail_id = pd.id)
    WHERE pd.product_id = -- ID-HERE
)
SELECT
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(colorsName) AS colorsName,
    amountColors
FROM (
    SELECT
        JSON_OBJECT(
            'color', v.name
        ) AS colorsName,
        COUNT(v.id) AS amountColors
    FROM variation v
        INNER JOIN grid g
            ON (g.id = v.grid_id)
    WHERE g.name = 'Color' AND EXISTS (TABLE cte)
    GROUP BY v.id
    LIMIT 1
) v

/* Test: LIMIT 1
array(2) {
  ["colorsName"]=>
  string(20) "[{"color": "Black"}]"
  ["amountColors"] => int(1) // should return int(2)
}*/

/* Test: LIMIT 2
array(2) {
  ["colorsName"]=>
  string(40) "[{"color": "Black"}, {"color": "White"}]"
  ["amountColors"] => int(1) // should return int(2)
}
*/
```

MySQL version: 8.0+

Comment: You need a separate subquery to get the count of all colors without limiting.

Comment: @Barmar thanks. I already imagined that there would be no other option

Comment: Provide a sample as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts (3-5 rows per table) and table-formatted desired output for different LIMIT input parameter. Specify **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: @Akina The only concrete solution is to separate the query. Problem solved ! Thanks

Comment: *The only concrete solution is to separate the query.* Incorrect statement.

Comment: @Akina https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rMsAqVYoTXJCqJunCz76X3/0 I really had no other option. If you know, I would be very grateful. Note: I removed the CTE because db-fiddle displays syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this query:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT p.id p_id, p.name p_name,
           pd.id pd_id, pd.price pd_price, pd.stock pd_stock,
           pdv.id pdv_id,
           v.id v_id, v.name v_name,
           g.id g_id, g.name g_name,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY pd.product_id) v_count,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pd.product_id ORDER BY v.id) v_rn,
           JSON_OBJECT( 'color', v.name ) AS ColorName
    FROM product p
    JOIN product_detail pd ON p.id = pd.product_id
    JOIN product_detail_variation pdv ON pd.id = pdv.product_detail_id
    JOIN variation v ON v.id = pdv.variation_id
    JOIN grid g ON v.grid_id = g.id
    WHERE g.name = 'Color'
      AND pd.product_id = 1
)
SELECT p_name ProductName,
       JSON_ARRAYAGG(ColorName) AS ColorNames,
       v_count ColorsAmount
FROM cte
WHERE v_rn <= @colors_limit
GROUP BY 1, 3
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab5964e632ea344dccf791dbcfaf7589)

Check it. The logic of the task is not completely clear for me now, I may be wrong...

And I recommend you to expand source data (add rows) and check again (with and without the condition by the product).

Comment: Why the use of "1, 3" in GROUP BY ?

Comment: @JonathanSilva https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html, "Columns selected for output can be referred to in ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses using column names, column aliases, or **column positions**."

Comment: I noticed a small problem in my tests. When the product has repeated colors 'Black P' and 'Black PP'. Returns Black twice. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7b3f7d1d19831a8417afd1b31e162671

Comment: @JonathanSilva Add second CTE which will distinct the colors before their aggregation in outer query/